# Update Sql- The actual date needs to be the date that the running tally exceeds the negative amount

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to update first negative transaction's Date value with the first positive transaction's date that has amount greater or equal to the first negative transaction's date.
For eg: if the first medical transaction is -60, but the first positive medical transaction is only $20, we have to find the date that the medical payments add up to at least $60 and update with that date value.

Have tried this, but this only looks for the first positive amount and then sets the negative's date to the first positive's date.

```
 create table staging.dbo.TMPPAYDATES (
        Clmno varchar(11) not null,
        FirstPositiveIndPaydt datetime null,
        FirstNegativeIndPaydt datetime null,
        FirstPositiveMedPaydt datetime null,
        FirstNegativeMedPaydt datetime null,
        FirstPositiveExpPaydt datetime null,
        FirstNegativeExpPaydt datetime null)
        on [PRIMARY]

insert into staging.dbo.TMPPAYDATES
        select c.clmno
        ,min(case when p.paytyp = 'IP' and p.amount > 0 then p.PAYDT else null end)
        ,min(case when p.paytyp = 'IP' and p.amount < 0 then p.PAYDT else null end)
        ,min(case when p.paytyp = 'MP' and p.amount > 0 then p.PAYDT else null end)
        ,min(case when p.paytyp = 'MP' and p.amount < 0 then p.PAYDT else null end)
        ,min(case when p.paytyp = 'EP' and p.amount > 0 then p.PAYDT else null end)
        ,min(case when p.paytyp = 'EP' and p.amount < 0 then p.PAYDT else null end)
        from staging.dbo.claimsmaster c with (nolock)
        join staging.dbo.Pmnts p with (nolock) on c.clmno = p.clmno
        where p.paytyp like '_P'
        group by c.clmno

update p
        set p.PAYDT = t.FirstPositiveIndPaydt
        from staging.dbo.TMPPAYDATES t
        join staging.dbo.PMNTS p on t.Clmno = p.CLMNO
        where p.PAYTYP = 'IP'
        and p.AMOUNT < 0
        and p.PAYDT < t.FirstPositiveIndPaydt
```

SO for example :

```
select clmno,paytyp,paydt,AMOUNT
from PMNTS
where CLMNO = 'A'
and PAYTYP ='IP'
order by PAYDT

clmno       paytyp  paydt                 AMOUNT  
A             IP    2001-10-26 00:00:00    -344
A             IP    2001-10-28 00:00:00    -155
A             IP    2001-11-20 00:00:00    150.5
A             IP    2001-12-05 00:00:00    451.5
A             IP    2001-12-24 00:00:00    503.6
```

Paydt having amount -344 should be updated with paydt having amount 451.5
But, the above code is just updating first negative amount's date with first positive amount's date.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results as *text tables* in the question.

Comment: You thought about how easy this would be if when the transcationdate was recorded you also recorded the current value and the transaction amount.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please don't ask sample data as text tables. Ask for DDL+DML instead, so that we could copy it to a test environment and play around if we need to.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)